# WP7 Migrate IsolatedStorageSettings while App update

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

**Scenario:**
Version 1.0.0.0 of my App uses certain **IsolatedStorageSettings** say Key = ID and Value being an object having numbers 1,2 and 3. Now, I update my App to version 1.1.0.0 and the logic in the new version assumes four numbers for ID. Number 3 becomes 4 and a new operation is mapped to the new number 3.
This calls for a data migration in the **IsolatedStorageSettings** at the time of App update.

My question is that is there any standard way of doing such migration since this seems to be a standard scenario.

(If there is none, then I am planning to write a logic in Application Class constructor by checking if the Isolated Storage version number (another Settings) is same as the current App Version. If not then run the Migration logic required for the current version.
Is this approach correct?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any standard procedure but you could put the following code in Application_Launching method of your app.

```
if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count==3)
        {
            //remove all 3 settings
            //like IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("gps");
            // add new settings
            //like IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["offers"]="5";
        }
```

Comment: yes I am doing something similar in Application_Launching event, but I wanted to check if there's any documented method to do since the scenario looked common to me.